# What is the meaning of "MiN" in the context of a japanese web novel which is using gaming terminology?

Tags: meaning, words

I'm reading a japanese web novel on the website Syosetu and a term popped up which i can't figure out. The original paragraph where it appears is as follows:

```
HP 120 (14UP)

MP 122 (15 UP)



ViT 118 (13UP)

PoW 117 (13UP)

SpE 118 (15UP)

DeX 116 (14UP)

MiN 130 (16UP)

InT 134 (18UP)

Luk Max (限界突破)
```

What is the meaning of "MiN" here? (this web novel uses a lot of japanese video game lingo)

Comment: Looks like English lingo to me…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be about the Japanese language.

Answer (score 2):

MIN (or MND) next to INT usually refers to MIND (commonly translated as 精神, 精神力), which is typically related to resistance to magic.